# How to export an Android Studio project to a new GitHub branch in a specific Repository?

Tags: android, git, android-studio, github

I have some code I want to add to a new branch in an existing repository. I tried to 'share project to GitHub' under VCS, but it just makes a new repository in a master branch with my code. Is there an option to commit the code to a new branch in an existing repository through Android Studio? I even tried uploading all the files to a new branch on Github.com directly but too many files for that to be processed.

Answer (score 0):

`git checkout -b 'new-branch-name'` sentence creates a new branch and then you just commit the changes there

Comment: what about the repository, how would I put the new branch in a specific repository?

Comment: You should be already on the repository, when you start the project you download the repository right? so you have the repo locally and then you commit the changes to the same repo on github, the new branch will be automatically created on the repo on github

Comment: No thats the problem, I downloaded the code from the repo on github.com and just uploaded the zip file onto Android Studio separately so I never connected Android Studio to Github to pull the code. I just connected GitHub and want to commit my code to a new branch in the repo and that's where I'm running into problems.

Comment: Why don't you clone the repo instead?